# Modulus related proof help

Tags: proof-writing

I need to prove this via either direct proof, or contrapositive.

Unsure of the best way to approach this.

if $a \equiv b\mod n$ and $c \equiv d\mod n$, then $ac \equiv bd\mod n$

So far I have:

Suppose $a \equiv b\mod n$ and $c \equiv d\mod n$, then it follows that $n|(a-b)$ and $n|(c-d)$ but I am unsure on where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n \mid (a - b)$ and $n \mid (c - d)$, we know that there exist $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
\begin{align*}
nx &= a - b \\
ny &= c - d
\end{align*}
But then observe that:
\begin{align*}
ac - bd
&= ac - bc + bc - bd \\
&= c(a - b) + b(c - d) \\
&= c(nx) + b(ny) \\
&= n(\underbrace{cx + by}_{\in~\mathbb Z})
\end{align*}
Thus, we conclude that $n \mid (ac - bd)$ so that $ac \equiv bd \pmod n$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Another way to rewrite the statement
$$a\equiv b\pmod n$$
is
$$a=b+nt\quad\hbox{for some integer $t$}.$$
See if that helps.